# Append extra param for my Magento 2 entire site dynamically

Tags: magento2, url, parameter, querystring

my requirement is like one magento site with having some query params.
By starting website with **www.abc.com/?id=1-2-3** like this i want carry this query param my entire site can any one how can achieve this like i want add query param when they click on every link i need to show this query param. it's difficult to place url params in every link so any one have any idea to add one place it will append every link

Answer (score 1):

The url is generated in the file "vendor/magento/framework/URLs.php". Specify where you want to add the parameter. I do not recommend using this file. You need to understand in what context you need to add parameters and make changes to the level above this file. Overriding this file will change all url addresses.